# How to have second NAT on standby in case primary fails on the same public subnet on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How to have second NAT on standby in case primary fails on the same public subnet on AWS ? I have a case that some maintenance will be done by Amazon on my NAT for about two hours. I do not want to have an outage of service. Is there a way to create second NAT that can takeover during this time ?

Answer (score 2):

You use routing tables to direct traffic to the NAT, so there's no way to transparently redirect to a different NAT.

If you are committed to a NAT instance, I recommend that you preemptively route traffic to the new NAT and shut down the old one. Beware that you will break all outstanding connections when you do this.

A better option may be to replace the NAT instance with a NAT gateway, and let AWS manage the hardware. You'll still have a one-time interruption as you change the routing tables to point at the gateway rather than the instance.

Comment: To extend this answer... The NAT Gateway service is highly available within an AZ, so you don't need to worry about NAT Gateway failing. However, you should create one NAT Gateway per AZ in the VPC, so that it can handle an AZ outage.